# Kinematics CAD package for LaTeX

Tags: tikz-styles

Do any good libraries exist for drawing kinematics diagram in LaTeX.

I am looking for something similar to the following image.

[Duplicate](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19689/kinematics-cad-package-for-latex)

[image: Kinematics diagram]

Comment: It should be possible to produce this with `tikz-3dplot`. But it won't be as convenient as a CAD package, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can used software from this link https://alexdu.github.io/sketch-lib/